# How can I make data available to multiple child components in Angular?

Tags: angular, observable, angular-services, angular2-observables

I have an app in Angular and need some guidance about the best way to structure things. At the root level is a component `<App>`, with a child `Router-Outlet` component (which of course can resolve to a number of different components).

I have a Service Provider with a Subject that provides an object that multiple child components of the App component depend on. It seems to me that the best way to do this is to have the App component subscribe to the Subject, and update something whenever that Subject emits. Unfortunately, it's not quite clear to me what that something might be such that all the child components also have access to that value.

The alternative of having each individual component depend on the Service seems a little redundant, because each file then has the code:

```js
ngOnInit(){
    this.myService.myData.subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
    });
}
```

which defeats the DRY principle.

I'm not even sure I don't have an X-Y problem here. Basically, there is some data that multiple views need, that is retrieved asynchronously. This data may change over the lifetime of the app. Having the Provider/Subject/data structure I described above with Angular doing a little DI  seems a logical, if a tiny bit convoluted, way of implementing that.

How do I best do this?

Comment: have you read the official document about the data interactions between the component? There is [one of the methods](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service) which is most flexible. It is based on the service and observable.

Comment: @XinMeng Isn't that effectively what I'm already doing? That said, if it's accepted best practice, then I'll carry on as is, my misgivings notwithstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you'll want to use a service for managing local state (stuff shared between a batch of components) and NGRX for app-wide state.

In your case, if its app-wide and the scenario calls for it, then I'd recommend building a Store where you can dispense info to your components without injecting the service everywhere.

You'll still need to subscribe to the store in every component but its cleaner. Also, if your finding your violating the DRY principle, you could subscribe to the store in your service and use that to dispense info locally. However, if you ever need to change logic in your subscriptions this method wont work.

My advice, if its a big app, create a store and subscribe in your components for change.

Comment: If I do use a Redux Store, won't I still have to effectively inject that everywhere?

Comment: True, but there’s simply no other way to get around that.